# Realtek 8188 EE Wi-Fi Adapter Keeps Breaking

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, windows-8.1, drivers

I have an HP laptop (model: 15-f111dx) that I've had since December 2014. Recently, I've had some really frustrating issues dealing with the Wi-Fi that could be indicative of a larger problem, possibly hardware failure.

Lately I've had issues where when I reawake my computer after closing the lid for a while, the computer won't wake up, or will freeze, or in general my laptop can freeze when trying to login to the Wi-Fi or when trying to use Windows 8's built-in Netflix application (which as far as I know, has never been updated).

When these freezes happen, I have to hard reset by holding the power button. Almost invariably, upon rebooting, my Wi-Fi adapter driver will be gone and the Wi-Fi connection window shows that no connections are available, and upon looking at network adapters in Device Manager, the adapter is gone. However, when I view hidden devices, it is there.

My go-to solution thus far has been to uninstall the driver and reboot, or uninstall the driver, reinstall it using the HP Recovery Manager, and then reboot. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes closing the lid after booting when doing this and waiting a few minutes will then solve it.
However, today none of this has worked and I've resorted to using an ethernet cable.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is? My Wi-Fi adapter is specifically Realtek RTL8723BE/RTL8188EE. I've seen numerous issues on Google related to this particular adapter. I can't afford a new laptop or even a new wireless card right now, so I need to know if this is fixable, and if so, how.

Comment: Your problems does indicate a hardware problem, either your hdd or your adapter

Comment: Could you be more specific? How can I determine what the problem is, exactly? I've tried to get into the BIOS, but after trying F2, F8, F10 and F12 on boot, which are the usual keys, I can't seem to figure out how to get there. From what I know, there is a way to test for hardware failure in the BIOS using UEFI tools.